# ViewPager ,call fragments automatically

Tags: android, android-fragments

Good afternoon!

I have a method which crashed with NullPointerException if I call it immediately after launch , but If i slide through all fragments and then call the method, all works good. 
As far as as consider, smth not initialize. 
I need to fix this bug fast, so I want to slide through all fragments programatically between UI launch(in onCreateView or smth else).  How can I do this ?

Here is RootFragment  http://pastebin.com/VfmRbVpc
One of child fragments http://pastebin.com/XnftaqTH

I have a NullPointer in child fragment line 63

```
 elview = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expand_lv);
```

Thanks!

Comment: As you said you have missed some initialization.

Comment: Post the logcat or debug and see where are you getting null

Comment: please post your code and xml layout and logcat if you want to fix it fast

Comment: I see where I'm getting null. The code structure wrong so objects initialize in onCreateView method of each fragment. So I want to call all this onCreateViews before programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments in a ViewPager are created on in a lazily manner so If you need access to a Fragment thats further down the line, you should attach a [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to the ViewPager and execute the needed code when you reach the target index/position.